# Doctrine2 query orderBy with specific values first

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by

I am trying to apply several filters to one dql in Symfony using Doctrine. I want order it by several columns (although for the moment I am having problems just with one column) and I want show first values that matches with specific values. I will write a simple example to illustrate it about the result that I am searching:

```
col1                   col1
----                   -----
A                       B
B            =>         A
C                       C
W                       W
```

I was searching information about how to make it but I am a bit confused due to that some people says that I can't do it directly, other people says that it is possible using `case when` or `if/else`. I tried to use case when but without success. The code that I am using is the following:

**Updated code and error**

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('article')
                ->where('article.title LIKE :article')
                ->setParameter('title', '%'.$term.'%')
                ->addSelect('(CASE WHEN article.to = \'WOR\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS to')
                ->addOrderBy('article.to', 'ASC')
                ->getQuery();
```

And if I want set the "B" value as parameter, should I use setParameter after the addSelect?

Right now with the abovecode I am getting the following error:

```
Key "title" for array with keys "0, to" does not exist in result.html.twig at line 177.
```

Information related about how I call this method into my controller and pass it to twig template:

```
        $prodMan = $this->get('app.article.manager');
        $articles = $prodMan->getResults((string)"t", $page);
        $limit = 50;
        $maxPages = ceil($articles->count() / $limit);
        $thisPage = $page;
        return $this->render('result.html.twig', compact('categories', 'maxPages', 'thisPage', 'articles', 'images'));
```

And the twig template where I have the error:

```
<td><p>{{articles.title}}></p></td>
```

Result of `{{ dump(articles) }}`

```
Paginator {#475 ▼
  -query: Query {#484 ▼
    -_state: 2
    -_dql: "SELECT article, (CASE WHEN article.to = 'WOR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS to FROM AppBundle\Entity\Article article WHERE article.title LIKE :title ORDER BY article.to ASC"
    -_parserResult: null
    -_firstResult: 0
    -_maxResults: 50
    -_queryCache: null
    -_expireQueryCache: false
    -_queryCacheTTL: null
    -_useQueryCache: true
    #parameters: ArrayCollection {#483 ▼
      -elements: array:1 [▼
        0 => Parameter {#480 ▼
          -name: "title"
          -value: "%t%"
          -type: 2
        }
      ]
    }
    #_resultSetMapping: null
    #_em: EntityManager {#105 …10}
    #_hints: []
    #_hydrationMode: 1
    #_queryCacheProfile: null
    #_expireResultCache: false
    #_hydrationCacheProfile: null
  }
  -fetchJoinCollection: true
  -useOutputWalkers: null
  -count: 143
}
```

I executed the same dql query without the case when (with that dql I haven't any problem), and I compare the dumps in Twig and the only difference that I see is that in the other dql I am getting #483 and #482 indexes instead of #484 and #480 respectly

And I can't var_dump any position of the array, but the array has the right number of results, although I can't check if results are sorted in the right way
I am stuck with this problem and if someone could lead me to the right answer I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Kevin, can you update the Twig code section to show where you do the for loop?

Comment: See the second edit in my answer Kevin. I think that's the change you need.

Comment: Well, I am getting the results using the Paginator class to paginate the pages, but I think that the problem should be in other side... due to that if I remove the line of `cause when` I am getting all fine... @AlvinBunk

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if your query will work, but what if you change this line like so:

```
->addSelect('(CASE WHEN article.to = \'B\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HIDDEN to')
```

Escaping the quote, or:

```
->addSelect("(CASE WHEN article.to = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HIDDEN to")
```

That way the `B` is in quote. Again, not sure about the query itself.

---

**EDIT #2 - Based on dump of articles**

Looks like the dump is still a query.
You need to get the results like so:

```
$articles = $query->getResult();
```

Then pass the articles to you twig and render it.
Normally done like so:

```
return $this->render('result.html.twig', array(
        'articles' => $articles,
));
```

See if that works.
You might need changes, but the above code gives you some idea of what to do.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about escaping quotes; I updated my code and puts here the new error. It is so weird... as if the entity wasn't recognized and I think that in the `case when` I should use article.to instead of just to, but I get an error from Doctrine. If you have any other idea about the error let me know sir!

Comment: Hi Kevin. That's a Twig error, can you post how you send the query results to render your Twig file, and show us roughly what's around line 177 of the `result.html.twig` file? Maybe at least 5 lines before and after. Thanks! Seems like you are close to solving it!

Comment: Sure! I am going to update the question with that info!

Comment: I see you are passing in 'articles'. Did you mean to post: `<td><p>{{articles.title}}></p></td>` instead? Also, in case you have a for loop, can you show the Twig {{ dump }} values? Make a link to imgur of a picture?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I simply the code and put just the important (I did the same in my code now), what do you mean with dump values in Twig?

Comment: If you are using a debug URL in Symfony, which is just appending `app_dev.php` to your URL, you can add `{{ dump(articles) }}` in your Twig files and see what `articles` contains. Since you are getting the error, the Twig file won't be displayed, so just comment out around lines 177 where your for loop is.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that function in Twig. I added `{{dump(articles)}}` before the loop but I am just getting a white page in the browser

Comment: Try a separate dump for the other objects you are passing to twig just to see if the dump is working. It should. For example try `{{ dump(maxPages) }}`. You need to use the debug URL as well.

Comment: I tried it with maxPages now but same result, maybe I am not using the url in the right way. Right now, I am accesing my action following this url: `http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/search/1`

Comment: Looks correct. You should see the debug bar on the bottom something like this: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-web-debug-toolbar-and-profiler-enhancements

Comment: Yes, in other pages I have the debug bar, but now with the dump function I haven't see the previous error, but I don't see nothing more neither the debug bar

Comment: I am not sure, but I think my mistake could be on ''addselect'' when I rename ''article.to'' to ''to'', or maybe, when I make such rename, the result of the resolved query doesn't contains any object of article type but other different thing, because of this, I can't access to the object's properties, becuase it isn't an object, Do you understand what I mean (I may be wrong with all these, I don't know)

Comment: You haven't posted the respective Twig code. You might want to post some more so i understand what you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, sorry I couldn't connect before. I don't understand what you mean, I updated my question with `<td><p>{{articles.title}}></p></td>`, it is the line where I am getting the error. I was checking with more calm my code and now I can dump variables in twig, I will updated my question with the result of dump "articles" as you recommended me